# How to display Unicode data with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

```
table 'abc' data :

tid    title

  1      வெள்ளிக்கிழமை ஐ.

  2      கோலாகல தொடக்க 


$sql=mysql_query("select title from abd where tid='1'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$title = $row['title'];

echo $title;
```

### OutPut displaying like this:

```
????????????????
```

### But I want to display

```
வெள்ளிக்கிழமை ஐ.
```

### Solution

```
<?php
    mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");   

    $sql=mysql_query("select title from abd where tid='1'");

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $title = $row['title'];

    echo $title;

?>
```

Comment: Beautiful characters! Especially ஐ.

Comment: If this is PHP code, do _not_ use the old `mysql_*` API; switch to the newer (and safer) `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to set charachter encoding after `mysql_connect` function like this:

```
 mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'"); 
 mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 

 mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```

Comment: @JeffDavis They are different and you need to use all 3

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya try this: `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');`

Comment: If you are going to update a field using that getting from a select statement, execute the above configurations after select query execution.

Answer (score 10):

For new version of *PHP* which used `mysqli`, use this code after connect to mysql:

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
```

Comment: You are my hero bro!

Answer (score 7):

Try to make sure the browser recognizes the page as Unicode.

Generally, this can be done by having your server send the right `Content-type` HTTP header, that includes the charset you're using.

For instance, something like this should work :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo "வெள்ளிக்கிழமை ஐ";
```

If this works, and your dynamically generated page still doesn't :

- make sure your data in your MySQL database is in UTF-8 too

  - this can be set for each table, or even columns, in MySQL
- and make sure you are connecting to it using UTF-8.

Basically, all your application should use the same encoding :

- PHP files,
- Database
- HTTP server

Comment: I had to combine your answer and antyrat's answer to get it work

Answer (score 3):

execute query

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

right after connecting to database

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your mysql data format to **utf-8**, see this great article by oreilly:

.

**[Turning MySQL data to UTF-8](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html)**

.

After that make sure that your page's encoding type is **utf-8**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: @Srinivas Tamada: The final answer you chose did the same thing what has been told in the oreily article i posted the link above. Anyways, it is good that you found the solution. Thanks..

Comment: Link is dead, which is why answers should not be links.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');echo "<font face='Bamini' size='5'>" . "m.Nkhfd; Fkhh;" ."<br />";
echo "<font face='Bamini' size='10'>" . "m.Nkhfd; Fkhh;" ."<br />";
?>

or

<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo "à®µà¯†à®³à¯à®³à®¿à®•à¯à®•à®¿à®´à®®à¯ˆ à®";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

While inserting the data into a MySQL database using the relevant collation (ex. `utf8_general_ci` for Unicode characters, i.e Hindi). Also in use the PHP predefined function `utf8_decode` to display the characters in HTML.