# Unicode string php

Tags: php, string, unicode, echo

I have a question!
I want to print an unicode string in php (like 'سلام')!
but when I use echo only some ???  apear!!!

what whould I do???
This happens hen I want to cho string that retrieved from database!

```
echo 'سلام';
```

result is:

```
????
```

I tried using header function but that didn't help me!

Comment: Did you specify the proper character encoding?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, the question is perfectly valid. The solution I finally found to work is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446778/how-to-display-unicode-data-with-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do three things:

1. Make sure you're receiving the data as UTF-8 data.  For MySQL, query `SET NAMES 'utf8'` before selecting records.
2. Make sure you're using UTF-8 compatible functions when dealing with UTF-8 strings.
3. Make sure you're setting the output encoding as UTF-8.  For HTML, this can be done by setting the `Content-type` HTTP header to (e.g.) `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Of course, replace "UTF-8" with whatever encoding you want which supports the characters you need.  There's no need to change the database tables (except for possible performance gains).  You may need to change HTML templates, etc. if you decide on UTF-16 or something else which isn't (mostly) ASCII-compatible.

Comment: If you plan on storing unicode data in mysql, you need to use a charset which supports it. Per default, Mysql uses latin1, but you can switch to utf-8.

Comment: @troelskn, I'm assuming the data was already stored properly.  I mentioned changing database tables because, say, if the site switches to UTF-16, the database's data's character set doesn't need to be changed, because the conversion is made for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the used character encoding in the HTTP response. You can use the [`header` function](http://php.net/header):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

With this the output is declared to be HTML with the character encoding UTF-8. Note that you can’t use `header` when you’ve already sent data to the client without buffering it. So either use the [output control](http://php.net/book.outcontrol) to buffer the output so that you can modify the header although there already was some output or use `header` before any output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little too late but this worked for me:

```
echo utf8_encode('سلام');
```