# PHP json decode with æøå

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with some json decode of my products, which have special characters "æøå".

Decode code + echo:

```
$products = json_decode($details['items'],true);
foreach($products as $pro){
..
<?php echo $pro['name']; ?>
..
```

In my database the name of the product looks like this: 'SpÃ¥ner'. However, in the echo it's: 'Spu00e5ner'. It need to be 'Spåner'.

I know the code isn't updated, but there gotta be a way to show the special characters.

Comment: This looks like an issue with unicode characters not being properly handled (U+00e5 decodes to å). Could the answers in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650754/unicode-string-php) be helpful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function that might help you with your problem.

```
function convertChars($char){

$return = html_entity_decode(htmlentities($char, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES , 'ISO-8859-15');
$return = iconv("UTF-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT",$return);
return strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/','',$return));
```

}