# PHP Unicode in Korean

Tags: php, unicode, bitnami

So I've recently had to work on some web application that needed to be available in Korean, and I ran into the issue of unicode not working for me.

I looked at this answer, and tried these suggestions with no luck.
[Unicode string php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650754/unicode-string-php)

Here is my simple code :

```
<?php

header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');

echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
';

echo '안녕하세요<br>';  

echo '</body>
</html>';

?>
```

All I get in my browser window are question marks...???????

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

If it matters I am using the Bitnami WAPP Stack 5.6.8-0...that includes Apache 2.4.12 and PHP 5.6.8

Comment: Most likely you didn't save the .php file in UTF-8 encoding in your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in you html code. You don't close head tag, you don't have html tag.
Look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My webpage</title>
<body>
    <p>안녕하세요</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You are making basic error in HTML. Read through documentation a little to get a grasp on it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I never had an issue with HTML....I just realized my editor....PSpad...was not saving the file format in UTF-8... This is one of the moments where I've been up all night and I was not thinking clearly....time to go to sleep...thanks again...