# php save special symbols into database

Tags: symbols

I want to save some special symbols in mysql database. Like ♫ and ♪ from here

http://www.alt-codes.net/music_note_alt_codes.php

But these inserted as ? mark in database. Can any one help in it

Comment: Try to set character encoding in MySQL, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446778/how-to-display-unicode-data-with-php