# Got error 'nothing to repeat at offset 1' from regexp

Tags: php, mysql, regex, full-text-search

I use php to send and receive data from mysql database 
my query is

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

  SELECT 
   *
  FROM
   test
  WHERE
   MATCH(word) AGAINST('+hello ')      
) AS fulltext_scan
WHERE 
 fulltext_scan.word REGEXP '^hello '
```

when I search for english word its working well
but when I search for swedish(ä,ö,å) word I got this error

```
Got error 'nothing to repeat at offset 1' from regexp
```

I have `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'")` in my connection and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

when I test the query directly from phpmyadmin its working well even with swedish words

I want to use `AS` for sorting like

```
SELECT  pages.*, MATCH (head, body) AGAINST ('some words') AS
      AND  column REGEXP '^hello ' relevance,
        MATCH (head) AGAINST ('some words') AS title_relevance
    FROM  pages
    WHERE  MATCH (head, body) AGAINST ('some words')
    ORDER BY  title_relevance DESC, relevance DESC
```

to get {hello} first

how can I fix that in my php page?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but the query working on phpmyadmin directly

Comment: Maybe `fulltext_scan.word like 'hello %'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:  What do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide an example string with the swedish characters?

Comment: when I search for "hello" the code working in my php page but when I search for "ögon" I just get the error

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446818/3832970. The error is certainly originating from the fact that the accented letters are turned to bytes and the first byte is a quantifier (I suspect `?`).

Comment: [This resource](https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql) might turn out useful.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Caution...  There are good points about that 'resource'.  But, it has several incorrect statements that have not been fixed in years.  One has to read all the Comments and hope that they are more correct.

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal?  To see if `word` *starts with* `ögon`?  *That* task can very efficiently be done with

```
WHERE word LIKE 'ögon %';
```

together with `INDEX(word)`, assuming it is a `VARCHAR`, not a `TEXT`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE test`.  There could be issues with the `CHARACTER SET`.

What do you get with `SELECT HEX(word) ...`?  If you are properly using utf8/utf8mb4, it should show `C3B6 67 6F 6E` (without spacing).

Unless you are using MySQL 8.0, do not expect `REGEXP` to properly understand accented letters.

There is possibly no need for the extra `SELECT`; simply do

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(word) AGAINST(...)
      AND word LIKE ...
```

The `MATCH` will happen first, then the `LIKE` will check the few rows that `MATCHed`.

Comment: thank you but I want to use ```AS``` for sorting like ```SELECT pages.*,
       MATCH (head, body) AGAINST ('some words') AS AND column REGEXP '^hello ' relevance,
       MATCH (head) AGAINST ('some words') AS title_relevance
FROM pages
WHERE MATCH (head, body) AGAINST ('some words')
ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, relevance DESC``` to get {hello} first

Comment: `AS AND` does not compute.  What is that a typo for?